# String manipulation: Display all characters to the left of "|" delimiter

Tags: vb.net

I am in need of help. I have a combobox that displays the following results

> A123456|Employee A

I then want to take the first 6 characters and place that result on a cell, so I worked out the following code:

```
    Private Sub cmbSelectEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbSelectEmployee.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim employeeInfo As String = cmbSelectEmployee.Text
    Dim employeeID = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(employeeInfo, 6)

    Globals.calCalculationSheet.Range("B36").Value = employeeID

End Sub
```

Works perfect, only that now I realized that the 6 digits left of the "|" will not always be 6. Sometimes is 5, other times may be 10.  So now I need to display all characters to the left of "|"

I used the Split("|"c)), but I could not figure out how to then place the left characters into a variable.

Comment: Split returns an array, in your case the left side will be `YourVariableName(0)` and the right side will be `YourVariableName(1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [String.IndexOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd.aspx) to find the index of a character in a string:

```
Dim employeeID = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(employeeInfo, employeeInfo.IndexOf("|"))
```

Note that `String.IndexOf()` will return -1 if the string does not contain the character that you request.  If you are not sure that your string will always contain the `|` you will need to test the return value of `String.IndexOf()`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly, I was pretty sure I was close to an answer, but after 13 hours of looking at code, I could not think anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
Private Sub cmbSelectEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbSelectEmployee.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim employeeInfo As String = cmbSelectEmployee.Text
    Dim employeeID = employeeInfo.Split("|")(0)

    Globals.calCalculationSheet.Range("B36").Value = employeeID

End Sub
```

Comment: being vb, `Split("|"c))[0]` would become `Split("|"c)(0)`. no square brackets, all round brackets.